# MySQL pivot based on view or 3-table query

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I'm looking to summarise a query across tables in a single view but am stuck!  Simplified version below:

Table 1 `users`:

```
usrID      usrName
1          Adam
2          Ben
3          Charlie
```

Table 2 `groups`:

```
grpID      grpName
A          Soccer
B          Baseball
C          Golf
```

Table 3 `users2groups`:

```
usrID      grpID      accessLevel
1          A          a
2          A          e
2          C          v
3          B          v
```

Which I'd like to summarise with:

```
usrName    Soccer    Baseball     Golf
Adam       a         NULL         NULL
Ben        e         NULL         c
Charlie    NULL      v            NULL
```

I've managed to create a query that will list all of the entries and saved it as a MySQL view called `permissions`:

```
SELECT users.usrName, groups.grpName, users2groups.accessLevel FROM ((`users` JOIN `groups`) LEFT JOIN `users2groups` ON (((`users2groups`.`usrID` = `users`.`usrID`) AND (`users2groups`.`grpID` = `groups`.`grpID`)))))
```

From looking here and elsewhere I've found a pivot table function along the lines of:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
  'MAX(IF(grpName = ''',
  grpName,
  ''', value, NULL)) AS ',
  grpName
)
) INTO @sql
FROM permissions;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT usrName, ', @sql, ' FROM permissions GROUP BY usrID');
```

But when I try to run this using my MySQL view in MySQL Workbench I get `Error Code: 1146. Table 'MYDB.permissions' doesn't exist`.  I tried simply replacing `"permissions"` with the query the view is based on from above (in brackets) but while it seems to run with no errors, I don't get a result set displayed.

Comment: can you create an example on [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)? It would be easier to see what's wrong

Comment: does this do it? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd8c3/3/0

Comment: you didn't put the `permissions` table in your SQL fiddle. Coult you please add it?

Comment: I've put the `permissions` view into the fiddle but can't seem to put the above query (starting `SET @sql = NULL`) into the fiddle and have it stay on refresh/share (because that's the part that's wrong?)

Comment: Please paste the link to your updated SQL fiddle

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise the link changed - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07f6b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is built correctly, except for some details:

1. You forgot to include the `usrId` field in your view (you use it in your pivot query, so you need to put it)
2. What is that `value` field you put in your pivot query? I think you mean `accessLevel`.

Besides those two little errors, I see no other problem.

The final step when you do this kind of thing is to create a prepared statement to run the query stored in the `@sql` variable.

Below I add the corrected script, and it's link to SQL fiddle (I use `case ... end` instead of `if()` in the pivot query construction, but that's just a matter of preference):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f10f49/2)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
    (`usrID` int, `usrName` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`usrID`, `usrName`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Adam'),
    (2, 'Ben'),
    (3, 'Charlie')
;


CREATE TABLE groups
    (`grpID` varchar(1), `grpName` varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO groups
    (`grpID`, `grpName`)
VALUES
    ('A', 'Soccer'),
    ('B', 'Baseball'),
    ('C', 'Golf')
;


CREATE TABLE users2groups
    (`usrID` int, `grpID` varchar(1), `accessLevel` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO users2groups
    (`usrID`, `grpID`, `accessLevel`)
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 'a'),
    (2, 'A', 'e'),
    (2, 'C', 'v'),
    (3, 'B', 'v')
;
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `permissions` AS
    (SELECT 
            `users`.`usrId` as `usrId` -- You forgot to include this column in the view (you use it in your pivot query)
          , `users`.`usrName` AS `usrName`
          , `groups`.`grpName` AS `grpName`
          , `users2groups`.`accessLevel` AS `accessLevel`
    FROM
        ((`users`
        JOIN `groups`)
        LEFT JOIN `users2groups` ON (((`users2groups`.`usrID` = `users`.`usrID`)
            AND (`users2groups`.`grpID` = `groups`.`grpID`))))
)
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
SET @sql = NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f10f49/2/0)**: (No results)

**Query 2**:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
                    CONCAT(
                      'max(case grpName 
                               when ''', grpName, ''' then accessLevel 
                               else null
                           end) as `', grpName, '`'
                    )
                   ) INTO @sql
FROM permissions
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f10f49/2/1)**: (No results)

**Query 3**:

```sql
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT usrName, ', @sql, ' FROM permissions GROUP BY usrID')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f10f49/2/2)**: (No results)

**Query 4**:

```sql
-- Prepare the statement
prepare stmt from @sql
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f10f49/2/3)**: (No results)

**Query 5**:

```sql
-- Execute the statement
execute stmt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f10f49/2/4)**:

```sql
| usrName | Soccer | Baseball |   Golf |
|---------|--------|----------|--------|
|    Adam |      a |   (null) | (null) |
|     Ben |      e |   (null) |      v |
| Charlie | (null) |        v | (null) |
```

**Query 6**:

```sql
-- When you're done, don't forget to deallocate the prepared statement
deallocate prepare stmt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f10f49/2/5)**: (No results)

Comment: Worked it through step by step based on the errors you pointed out.  My original version of query 2 didn't quote the grpName in ``as grpName`` so the query broke when grpName had a fullstop (.) in it (in case anyone should try to follow that).  With your version I'm up and running.  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @Adam Happy to help. I've posted quite some answers about pivot tables in MySQL... [You may want to check them out](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A355931+[mysql]+pivot)